# Using an array in a recursive algorithm to find combinations

Tags: java, recursion

The idea is if i am at a certain stair i can either go one step down or two so if am at  stair 3 i can go down 1 1 1 or 2 1 for example. My code should print all the possibilities. The error I get is that I can't convert the add function to an array (since the add method is a boolean). What is wrong with this algorithm?

```
public class Stairs {

public static void staircase (int height  ){

    ArrayList<Integer> Array = null;
    explore (height,Array);
}
public static void explore(int objheight,ArrayList<Integer>Array){
    int intialheight = 0; 
    if (intialheight == objheight){
        Array.toString();
    }
    else{ if (objheight > intialheight ){
        explore(objheight-2,Array.add(2));
        explore(objheight-1,Array.add(1));
    }
}
```

after your feedback I am getting an empty output 
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Stairs {

public static void staircase (int height  ){

    ArrayList<Integer> Array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    explore (height,Array);
}
public static void explore(int objheight,ArrayList<Integer>Array){
    int intialheight = 0; 
    if (intialheight == objheight){
        Array.toString();
    }
    else{ if (objheight > intialheight ){
        Array.add(2);
        explore(objheight-2,Array);
        Array.add(1);
        explore(objheight-1,Array);
    }
}}
public static void main (String args[]){
staircase(3);

   }
 }
```

Comment: What does "convert the add function to an array" mean? And I am pretty sure you are getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

The method `add(E e)` in ArrayList returns `true` upon appending the element `e` passed as a parameter to the end of the ArrayList.

Your method, `explore(int objHeight, ArrayList<Integer> Array)` does not accept a boolean for its second parameter. Yet, in that same method, `explore`, you are recursively calling `explore` and passing in a boolean to the method.

The following code should be modified to first invoke the `add` method of `Array` and then pass `Array` to the `explore` method.

Before:

`explore(objheight-2,Array.add(2));` This code is passing parameters `int` and `boolean` to the `explore` method, which is not the parameters it accepts. You should instead attempt the following.

After:

`Array.add(2);
explore(objheight-2,Array);` This code first adds 2 to the `Array` and then passes the `Array` to the `explore` method without invoking any further methods on the `Array` object.

---

You will also need to do this for the next line of code, where you have `explore(objheight-1,Array.add(1));`.

---

Edit: Upon further examination of the code, I discovered another (sooner) error that occurs. A NullPointerException will occur each time the program runs:

`ArrayList<Integer> Array = null;
explore (height,Array);`

Then inside the `explore` method, different methods on `Array` are invoked, despite `Array` always being `null`:

`Array.toString();`, `Array.add(2)` and `Array.add(1)`.

The `Array` object must be initialized inside of either the `staircase` or `explore` methods.

`ArrayList<Integer> Array = new ArrayList<Integer>();` or `ArrayList<Integer> Array = null;
Array = new ArrayList<Integer>();`